# CGContextFillPath(context) gets removed when creating a line

Tags: iphone, ios, core-graphics, cgcontextref

I use the below code for fill path in `viewDidLoad`it works perfect

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(_drawingPad.frame.size);
CGContextRef context1 = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextMoveToPoint(context1, 300, 300);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context1, 400, 350);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context1, 300, 400);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context1, 250, 350);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context1, 300, 300);

CGContextClosePath(context1);
//CGContextStrokePath(context1);

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context1, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
CGContextFillPath(context1);
CGContextStrokePath(context1);
```

also I'm creating a line when touches begin..
but the fill path get erased before I create the line..

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
CGContextFillPath(context1);
CGContextStrokePath(context1);
```

by

```
CGContextDrawPath(context1, kCGPathFillStroke);
```

That will fill *and* stroke the current path without erasing it in between.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. but again the problem happened when i create another object for CGContextRef.. old path get erased.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to draw path without creating a path.

Try the following:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(_drawingPad.frame.size);
CGContextRef context1 = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

CGPathMoveToPoint(path,300,300);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path,400,350);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path,300,400);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path,250,350);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path,300,300);

CGPathCloseSubpath(path);

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context1, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context1, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);


CGContextAddPath(context1,path);

//Now you can fill and stroke the path
CGContextFillPath(context1);
CGContextStrokePath(context1);

CGPathRelease(path); //free up memory
```

Comment: OP *is* creating a path in the current graphics context. Your code creates a separate CGMutablePathRef first and then adds it to the current context. That is of course also valid, but (as I assume) independent of OP's problem. I may of course be wrong :-)